# PHP | Online Notepad

Tags: php, vb.net

I recently made a Chat application in Visual Basic using PHP.

I used this code:

```
<?php
$msg = $_GET['w'];
$logfile= 'Chats.php';
$fp = fopen($logfile, "a");
fwrite($fp, $msg);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

I'm now trying to make a Online Notepad.
What i want to do is in Visual Basic create a unique ID.
That unique ID, has to be his filename.
I'm not very good with PHP so what i want to know is:

I want the unique ID to be the filename of the "Note".
Like: 
`$logfile= '{uniqueID.php}';`

Whenever the user opens the program, it'll open his uniqueID.php file and he can edit that in my program.

Long Story Short (TL;DR)

- Program generates uniqueID
- uniqueID is going to be a new file; {uniqueID}.php
- On next open it will check if {uniqueID}.php of him/her exists else it will make a new one.

I know this isn't really secure but it's to learn something for myself.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

```
$file = uniqid(true).'.php'; // generate unique filename
if(!file_exists($file)) { // if filename doesn't exist
    file_put_contents($file, 'New user'); // write something to the file
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but, i want the UniqueID (it's a HWID) in my program to be the name of the uniqueid.php.
I hope you can help.

Comment: @user2947423: How are you getting this `HWID` in your PHP script?